# Python Dataframe: Get alternative days based on month?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I have df with column `salary_day`

```
            salary_day
    0       thursday
    1       friday
```

I'm trying to get alternative dates present for each day.

For `May 2020`:

thursdays in may :  `7,14,21,28`
,fridays in may :  `1,8,15,22,29`

Expected output for alternative Thursday and Friday for the month of `May`:

df

```
salary_day        req_dates
thursday           7,21 
friday           1,15,29
```

For `June 2020`:

Thursdays in june :  `4,11,18,25`
Friday in june :  `5,12,19,26`

As there are 5 fridays in may , first friday in june is not an alternative day and should be excluded and 12,26 should be considered

expected output for alternative Thursday and Friday for the month of `June`:

df

```
salary_day        req_dates
thursday           4,18
friday             12,26
```

Edit1: For all weekdays

For month of May

```
      salary_day        req_dates
0     Monday            4,18
1     Tuesday           5,19
2     Wednesday         6,20
3     Thursday          7,21
4     Friday           1,15,29 
5     Saturday         2,16,30 
6     Sunday           3,17,31
```

Comment: Somewhere the year has to be specified as well.

Comment: Updated with current year

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "alternate" day? Why is friday june `12,26` ?

Comment: Looks like starting with the first occurrence of Thursday, the salary must be processed every alternate Thursdays and Fridays. May was an exception as in May first Friday was on 1st of the month.

Comment: So you also have a starting month, so it does not start at 1s of january? That is an important detail you didnt provide.

Comment: Apologies, could not understand what you mean. The scope for this is each month. Unless I am missing something. May be OP can clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most clean and general way to do this is create a a help table with all the days of the specified year. And create extra columns: `month, day_name, day`.

Then to check which `day_names` are in `df['salary_day`]`.

After this we check if the `day` is un-even, by: `day % 2 > 0`.

Finally we `GroupBy.agg` and join the `day` as string by `,`:

```
# create salary days to get altnerative days
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
df = pd.DataFrame({'salary_day': days})

START_MONTH = 5
YEAR = 2020

def create_dates(y, month_start):
    dates = pd.date_range(f'{y}-{str(month_start).zfill(2)}-01', f'{y}-12-31')
    dates = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates})
    dates['month'] = dates['dates'].dt.month
    dates['day_name'] = dates['dates'].dt.day_name().str.lower()
    dates['day'] = dates['dates'].dt.day
    return dates


def get_alternative_dates(salary_days, y, month_start):
    df_dates = create_dates(y, month_start)

    m = df_dates['day_name'].isin(salary_days)

    months = df_dates[m].copy()
    months['day'] = months['day'].astype(str)
    months['rank_days'] = months.groupby('day_name')['day'].cumcount().add(1)

    months = months[months['rank_days'].mod(2).ne(0)]
    df_final = months.groupby(['month', 'day_name'])['day'].agg(','.join).reset_index()

    return df_final

get_alternative_dates(df['salary_day'], YEAR, START_MONTH)
```

**Output**

```
    month  day_name      day
0       5    friday  1,15,29
1       5  thursday     7,21
2       6    friday    12,26
3       6  thursday     4,18
4       7    friday    10,24
5       7  thursday  2,16,30
6       8    friday     7,21
7       8  thursday    13,27
8       9    friday     4,18
9       9  thursday    10,24
10     10    friday  2,16,30
11     10  thursday     8,22
12     11    friday    13,27
13     11  thursday     5,19
14     12    friday    11,25
15     12  thursday  3,17,31
```

Comment: Thanks, Erfan. How to include all days of week in above code

Comment: See edit on top, remove or add the days you want to get the altnerative from in the list `days`. @Zanthoxylumpiperitum

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
# for read_clipboard()
'''
salary_day
thursday
friday
'''

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
```

.

```
  salary_day
0   thursday
1     friday
```

.

```
import calendar

c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)

year = 2020; month = 5

monthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
fridays = [(str(day)[-2:]) for week in monthcal for day in week if \
                day.weekday() == calendar.FRIDAY and \
                day.month == month]
thursdays = [(str(day)[-2:]) for week in monthcal for day in week if \
                day.weekday() == calendar.THURSDAY and \
                day.month == month]

# Friday will be the first salary day of the month only if it occours on 1st
if int(thursdays[0]) < int(fridays[0]):
   fridays = fridays[1:] 


df['req_dates'] = ''

print(df)

df.loc[df['salary_day'] == 'thursday', 'req_dates'] = ','.join(thursdays[::2])
df.loc[df['salary_day'] == 'friday', 'req_dates'] = ','.join(fridays[::2])
```

Output:

```
  salary_day req_dates
0   thursday     07,21
1     friday  01,15,29
```

For the month of June:

```
year = 2020; month = 6
```

Output:

```
  salary_day req_dates
0   thursday     04,18
1     friday     12,26
```

Comment: But for `June` month. Req output for `Friday` is `12,26` instead of `05,19`.Because there are 5 Fridays in  May.

Comment: Fixed that as well, please check now

Comment: Thanks Anshul, It worked for this use-case. If I want to have it for all days of the week,
What changes should be done.

Comment: All days as in? Can you clarify?

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output?

Comment: Updated the question for month of May

Comment: Haha. Thats a totally different scenario :D. You are looking to skip every alternate week and then distribute the dates daywise.